# I try to use usblib in Dev-c++, but get "undefined reference"?

Tags: c++, static-libraries, linker-errors, dev-c++, libusb

I am trying to use libusb for an c++ application, but I get the error: "Undefined reference" for all libusb functions.

- "undefined reference to 'usb_init'
- "undefined reference to 'usb_find_busses'
- and so on..

Clearly I have a not linked properly to the libusb library, but I don't know how to do it right and fix this?

I am using the IDE Dev-C++, and I've installed the libusb library by:

- #include "lusb0_usb.h" in my main.c
- added the linker parameter/option: libusb-win32-bin-1.2.6.0\lib\gcc\libusb.a

Both operations seems to be fine since the compiler/linker doesn't complain about any missing files.
I am really at the bare bottom at the moment, so any help or suggestions are really appreciated.

Comment: What compiler are you using?   The intel compiler?  Don't think they are compatible with the Gnu libs.

Comment: I am using TDM-GCC MinGW 4.8.1 :-)

Answer (score 1):

I found the error.

As mentioned in the question, I linked to the "libusb.a" file. Problem is, i am running on Windows x64. Therefore I had to link to the appropriate libusb.lib file instead.